# fetching data and trying to create a loop to determine lowest value

Tags: php

This is going to be a newbie question, so bear with me.

I have a database in which I fetch the data, I would like to create a `for` loop which will loop through the fetched data and will determine what the lowest time is. This is how my loop looks like: (take into consideration I only took the part out that seemed usefull to post, and `$row['timePV']` is a time based value such as: 23:00)

```
    $arrayCount = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo $row['timePV'];
            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";   
        array_push($arrayCount,$row['timePV']);                                         
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
$c = 100000;
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arrayCount); $i++) {
    $arrayCount[$i];
    if ($arrayCount[$i] < $c) {
        $c = $arrayCount[$i];
        echo $c;
    } else {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

So what I want to achieve: Loop through the stored data and take out the lowest value and display that value, but it only displays all the values.

So my question: How can I make the loop in such way that it will take the lowest value and display it to me?

Comment: Why don't you just use [min](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php)?

Comment: _“This is going to be a newbie question, so bear with me.”_ - bearing … still bearing … hm, nothing. Where is the actual _question_?

Comment: Or at least do the min check as part of the original while loop. No need to write an array and do 2 loops

Comment: I did read something about min, but since i'm quite new to php (not very experienced) I decided to take a route that's a bit more familiar.

Comment: If you are looping over the whole data set in a while loop already, and only need the minimum value afterwards - then you don’t need a _second_ loop, you can just determine the minimum directly in that first loop.

Comment: Made the edit so u don't have to wait any longer for the question.

Comment: _“Although to me it seems I did declare my variable?”_ - you did declare a variable `$i` in the for loop - but then you used the _constant_ `i` to try and access `$arrayCount[i]` …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do another loop to calculate lowesttime. You can do it in that while loop with checking previous and present timePv like following

```
    //$timeExample=[["timePV"=>"11:30"],["timePV"=>"11:20"],["timePV"=>"13:30"]];//example of data
 $lowestTime = null;//Deault defined it null
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  //foreach($timeExample as $row){ //foreach for run example 
      if($lowestTime){
          $lowestTime=min($lowestTime,strtotime($row['timePV']));//If not null we also get min lowerstTime from previous //and current one
      }else{
          $lowestTime=strtotime($row['timePV']);//It will work for only first iteration since $lowestTime will null in //first iteration
      }
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo $row['timePV'];
        echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";   
  }

  echo date("h:i",$lowestTime);//11:20 example out
```